# Divisibilty of $n^3+3$ and $n^5+5$ by a prime.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given that $n^3+3$ and $n^5+5$ are divisible by a prime $p$. How many values can $p$ take, with $n$ an integer?

The best I could do is $p=2$ for odd n, and I showed that $p$ cannot be equal to $3$. I know by subtracting the first equation to second, we will get 
$n^5-n^3+2=n^3(n-1)(n+1)+2$. The expression is clearly not divisible by $3$ which means $p$ cannot take value of $3$.

My only question is: Are there any values that $p$ can take? I've tried to solve it various ways, none worked.

If you can help me, I greatly appreciate it, thank you

Comment: For $n=10$, we have $p=59$. I guess there must be more primes like this, even though I'm currently unable to find any.

Comment: $p|n^3+3$ is equivalent to $n^3\equiv-3\pmod p$, that is, $-3$ is a *cubic residue*$\mod p$. Similarly $-5$ is a *quintic residue*$\mod p$. These residues are more complicated than the familiar quadratic residues and thus harder to deal with. Google them to find more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** $\ {\rm mod}\ p\!:\ \begin{align}\color{#0a0}{n^3\equiv -3}\\\color{#c00}{n^5\equiv -5}\end{align}\Rightarrow\, (\color{#0a0}{-3})^5 \equiv(\color{#0a0}{n^3})^5\equiv(\color{#c00}{n^5})^3\equiv(\color{#c00}{-5})^3\Rightarrow\, 0\equiv 3^5\!-5^3\equiv 2\cdot 59 $

Comment: This is simpler :-) In the case of binomials this gets the job done. Only in a more general setting is one forced to calculate the resultant.

Answer (score 4):

Assume that a prime $p$ divides both $a_1(n):=n^5+5$ and $a_2(n):=n^3+3$. Let's run Euclid on this...

1. Then $p$ also divides $a_3(n):=a_1(n)-n^2a_2(n)=5-3n^2$.
2. Therefore $p$ also divides $a_4(n):=3a_2(n)+na_3(n)=5n+9$.
3. Therefore $p$ also divides $a_5(n):=5a_3(n)+3na_4(n)=27n+25$.
4. Therefore $p$ also divides $a_6(n):=27a_4(n)-5a_5(n)=118=2\cdot59$.

So either $p=2$ or $p=59$. The former occurs whenever $n$ is odd. Ivan Neretin and Alex Jordan checked out that the latter occurs when $n\equiv10\pmod{59}$. No other primes can occur.

Comment: I seem to have inadvertently calculated the [resultant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant) of $n^3+3$ and $n^5+5$.

Comment: Elimination can be done much more simply and intuitively for cases like this - see my answer.

Comment: "$n=10$" can be upgraded to "$n\equiv10\mod{59}$".

Comment: Indeed, it can. Thanks @alex.jordan I (or rather, Mathematica) also ran a brute force check of that.